# Criteria Query select join

Tags: jpa, eclipselink, jpql, criteria-api

I need help to convert this JPQL query in Criteria Query:

```
SELECT u.documentList FROM Unit u WHERE u.id = :id
```

this is what i have tried:

```
CriteriaQuery<Document> query = builder.createQuery(Document.class);
Root<Unit> root = query.from(Unit.class);
Join<Unit, Document> join = root.join(Unit_.documentList);
query.select(join);
query.where(builder.equal(root.get(AbstractEntity_.id), entity.getId()));
```

executing this query result in a complex SQL query that returns an empty list.

IMO this should work, maybe it's a bug?

i'm using EclipseLink 2.5.2 as JPA provider and MySQL 5.6 as db.

here the generated SQL:

```
SELECT ... 
FROM UNIT t3 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN (DOCUMENT_RELATION t4 
    JOIN UNIT t0 ON (t0.ID = t4.CHILD_ID) 
    JOIN DELIVERABLE t1 ON (t1.ID = t0.ID) 
    JOIN DOCUMENT t2 ON (t2.ID = t0.ID)) ON (t4.PARENT_ID = t3.ID) 
WHERE (t3.ID = 58)

SELECT ... 
FROM DOCUMENT_RELATION t6, 
    DOCUMENT t5, 
    DELIVERABLE t4, 
    UNIT t3, 
    DOCUMENT t2, 
    DELIVERABLE t1, 
    UNIT t0 
WHERE (((t3.ID = 58) AND (((t5.ID = t3.ID) AND ((t4.ID = t3.ID) AND (t4.ID = t3.ID))) AND (t3.DTYPE = 'Document'))) AND ((((t5.ID = t3.ID) AND ((t4.ID = t3.ID) AND (t4.ID = t3.ID))) AND (t3.DTYPE = 'Document')) AND (((t6.PARENT_ID = t3.ID) AND (t0.ID = t6.CHILD_ID)) AND (((t2.ID = t0.ID) AND ((t1.ID = t0.ID) AND (t1.ID = t0.ID))) AND (t0.DTYPE = 'Document'))))) LIMIT 0, 10
```

here is the mapping:

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public abstract class Unit extends NamedEntity
{
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name = "DOCUMENT_RELATION", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "PARENT_ID"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "CHILD_ID"))
    protected List<Document> documentList = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

and here is the class hierarchy:

```
AbstractEntity (abstract @MappedSuperClass)
    NamedEntity (abstract @MappedSuperClass)
        Unit (abstract @Entity joined-inheritance)
            Deliverable (abstract @Entity)
                Document (concrete @Entity)
```

---

found solution:

```
CriteriaQuery<Document> query = builder.createQuery(Document.class);

Root<Unit> root = query.from(Unit.class);
root.alias("root");

Root<Document> relation = query.from(Document.class);
relation.alias("relation");

query.select(relation);

query.where
(
    builder.equal(root.get(AbstractEntity_.id), item.getId()),
    builder.isMember(relation, root.get(Unit_.actionList))
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying to achieve is forbidden by JPA spec. *single-valued path expressions* are valid in select clause but ***collection-valued path expressions* are not valid**. See chapter 4.8 of the spec. I cite *Pro JPA* book:

> The following query is illegal:
>   SELECT d.employees
>   FROM Department d

The same is applies for Criteria queries. Why not just query for `Unit` and call `getDocumentList()`?

EDIT:
You can also try to reverse the query:

```
SELECT d FROM Document d WHERE d.unit.id=:id
```

Comment: thanks i'll check the spec. I'm trying this because i need to enable pagination, filtering and sorting via JSF/PrimeFaces to relation collections. Some of these collections can have thousands of elements, so it's a performance issue too.

Comment: Thank you, i found the workaround: `SELECT d FROM Unit u, Document d WHERE d member of u.documentList`